# Reinstall cocoa pods mirror to make it work

Tags: ruby, cocoa

Several days earlier I met a strange issue,when imported the library of Alamofire and then let enum conform to protocol .The error shows enum cannot conform to protocol .I thought the issue was from cocoa pods ,so I uninstalled cocoa pods and then wanna install again.
I executed the order:"gem install cocoapods".But it displayed the error,the error as follow,I hope get everyone's help to solve it completely.I'm not skilled in the field of cocoa pods.Thank you so much..
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapods' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://ruby.taobao.org - no such name (https://ruby.taobao.org/specs.4.8.gz)
Sorry to disturb everyone......But I really desire to get your hand to solve it.

Comment: taobao.org is reporting some connection issues. Try again.

Comment: I retry again,but the issue is still existing.Could you give me the details to solve it?Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah  I did it via command order

```
pod install cocoapods
```

Sometimes you need to reinstall it and then all will be solved.